# Android: Run method in separate class from a home screen widget

Tags: java, android, widget

I have a method in a plain class file (not an activity) that I run from my main activity, and I also want to run it from my home screen widget.

The button in the widget works perfectly as long as the app is open in the background. If I close the app from recent tasks the button stops working.

I think I need to start the app with the button click as well, but I don't want it to open the main activity, just run the method. How can I do this?

Here is my code for the widget:

```
public class PanicWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static final String CLICK_PANIC = "PANIC";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.panic_widget);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PanicWidget.class);
        intent.setAction(CLICK_PANIC);

        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.panicbutton, actionPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if (CLICK_PANIC.equals(intent.getAction())){
            Methods.countdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the current code to handle onclick on the widget's button?

Comment: I've edited my post to include it all

Comment: And now I've confused myself more. Do I set up the action in the onReceive method of the widget, or in the onClick function of the button in the layout file? or both?

Comment: Just to clarify, what happens when you click the button? Does Methods.countdown() get run?

Comment: Yes it does, but it only works if my app is open in the background. If I remove it from recent apps then I get an "Unfortunately app has stopped" error.

Comment: Ok, so actually the button is working, just that whatever it is you are doing in Methods.countdown() doesn't work when the app is not open. Could you post what Methods.countdown() is doing?

Comment: Found the problem! countdown() was running another method that was accessing defaultSharedPreferences. It seems like if the app isnt open then there isnt a context that I can use to get to the preferences of my app. I guess I've got a different problem to solve now haha